# CPU mining on testnet using geth on ubuntu - eth.hashrate = 0

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, ropsten, hashrate, cpu

I have setup a CPU miner on ropsten testnet but when I run eth.hashrate it always returns zero. Can anyone tell me why this is? I have searched for an answer, but cannot find a satisfactory answer. I am doing this as a self learning exercise, so would really like to get this working on geth rather than using another medium

Exact setup steps were as follows

Sync ropsten blockchain

> $geth --testnet --fast --cache=1024

Once the entire blockchain synced, I verified that the latest blocknumber was correct

> $geth --testnet attach
>
> > eth.blockNumber

This returned the same blockNum as the the latest block number on Ropsten etherscan

I then created my first account i.e the etherbase account

> $geth --testnet account new

and secured with passphrase

I then began mining with

> $geth --testnet --mine

the output I get appears to be mining 
[image: Console output from geth miner]

However, my hashrate is always zero
[image: hashrate is zero]

Answer (score 2):

I was also mining on my private network for 30+ minutes and got 0 too.

I was also trying to figure out what's happening and found this:

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/fe6cf00f480aa6347b8d55079cbe6c473482ea27/miner/miner.go#L142

It looks like the function's name is either misleading or we fall into the race case (bug).

[image: Starting the miner and after, ether is increasing.]

[image: The screenshot from the running node's side]

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not familiar with golang nor with the geth codebase. But if it's a race condition, I would have thought I would at least sometimes get a non zero result.

One thing I did notice is that the return value is an integer. Could it be a resolution problem? I.e if my hashrate is KH/s and the return value of agent.GetHashRate() is specified in MH/s then the integer return value would just be rounded to zero everytime.....

Comment: I guess I should have asked. Did you mine any ether on your private network while it was saying your hashrate was zero?

Comment: I did not check the code thorougly, but maybe it worth sending an "Issue" to their GitHub.

Yes I have mined a few thousand ethers before and meanwhile checking the restult of miner.

Answer (score 0):

**Start mining with miner.start()**

You can also start and stop CPU mining at runtime using the console. miner.start takes an optional parameter for the number of miner threads.

> miner.start(8)
>   true
>
> miner.stop()
>   true

#### Another way to do the same

```
When you start up your ethereum node with geth it is not mining by default.
To start it in mining mode,
you can use geth --fast --cache=1024 --mine --minerthreads=8 --rpc
```

Comment: When you start up your ethereum node with geth it is not mining by default. To start it in mining mode,you can use   geth --fast --cache=1024 --mine --minerthreads=8 --rpc

Comment: I have tried both of these already. Hashrate is still zero